# MSMQ poison message means what?

Tags: msmq

I'm pretty new to this queue service and I don't know what really means poisoned message.

I read that is a message you cant consume, but It means you can Peek() and see the details but not Receive() or what?

From my point of view, I would say a poisoned message is a message on top of the queue that because of its format or even corrupted format is not consumible because the business in charge of handle it can't do it and it maybe generates a  exception that in a transactional scenario is catched and handled with a rollback, so the message stays on top forever.

What do you think? Am I totally wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to deal with poison MSMQ messages before, ugh! I'd say your definition is close.

A poison message is basically a message that is repeatedly read from a queue when the service reading the message cannot process the message because of an exception or some other issue and terminates the transaction under which the message is read. In such cases, the message remains in the queue is retried again upon next read from the queue. This can theoretically go on forever if there is a problem with the message.

For example, the message contained data that would violate a database constraint. I sometimes would create an error queue and have the service processing the messages throw the "poison" message into that if an exception occurred during processing. This would at least remove the message from the queue and give me an opportunity to view it later without effecting the main production queues.

[Here is some advice and information on poison message handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/poison-message-handling-in-msmq-4-0).

Comment: Thanks for your help mate.